# Long exact sequences and tensor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety and
$0\rightarrow  \mathcal{F}_1 \rightarrow  \mathcal{F}_2 \rightarrow \dots 
 \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_k
\rightarrow 0$ be a long exact sequence of coherent sheaves on $X$.

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be another coherent sheaf on $X$. 
Is there a natural conditions in terms of $\mathrm{Tor}$ functors such that 
the sequence $0\rightarrow  \mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{G} \rightarrow  \mathcal{F}_2 \otimes \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \dots 
 \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_k \otimes \mathcal{G}
\rightarrow 0$ is exact as well?

For example, if $k=3$ then is enough to impose $\mathrm{Tor}^{\mathcal{O}_X}_1( \mathcal{F}_k, \mathcal{G})=0$. Is it possible to generalize this for long exact sequences in general?

Comment: You could try breaking the sequence into short exact sequences. E.g. if $k=4$, then you get $0 \to \mathcal F_1 \to \mathcal F_2 \to \mathrm{coker} f_1$, where $f_1$ is the first map.